# Can I use both Offer and AggregateOffer?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have a product page, and the product can be bought from different sellers.

I saw Google [seperates](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product) between `AggregateOffer` and `Offer`, as if I should choose either that tag or the other.

I tried using both like this, and it returned a markup error when testing with the Google tool, because I used `offers` twice:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "MyName",
  "image": [
    "https://www.example.com/image1.jpg",
    "https://www.example.com/image2.jpg"
   ],
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "100",
    "highPrice": "150",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "offerCount": "3"
  }

      "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/page/",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "price": "100",
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
    "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
    "itemOffered": "Thing"
  }

}
```

I want to give as much info as possible, and according to Google, info such as `availability` applies to `Offer` rather than `AggregateOffer`.

So I have two options:

Either to use only one of the above `Offer` markups, or use the `AggregateOffer` and add inside it fields like `availability`, even though I did not see this as an example anywhere.

What will be better to do?

Answer (score 0):

An [`AggregateOffer`](https://schema.org/AggregateOffer) can reference all its [`Offer`](https://schema.org/Offer) items:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",

  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "offerCount": 3,

    "offers": [
      {
        "@type": "Offer"
      },
      {
        "@type": "Offer"
      },
      {
        "@type": "Offer"
      }
    ]

  }

}
```

According to [Google’s documentation about `AggregateOffer`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#aggregate_offer_properties), Google’s product rich result makes no use of the individual `Offer` items an `AggregateOffer` consists of, though.

Also note that `AggregateOffer` can have all the properties `Offer` can have (like `availability`), because `Offer` is the parent type, but these properties then apply to the aggregate offer itself, not to the individual offers it consists of, so most of these properties don’t make sense in this context.

Comment: for example, if all items offered are in stock, and brand new for example, it does make sense IMO.
for now I used AggregateOffer and under it placed everything the an Offer can have. I wonder how long it will take to see if Google actually respects any of the tags.